# How to use Spring Boot properties depending on the active profile

Tags: spring-boot

Let say my application.properties file of  my microservice looks like this.

```
server.port=8023
spring.profiles.active=staging
spring.application.name=service-ws
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://my.cloud.config.server:8012/
```

What I try to achieve is, when I change "spring.profiles.active" to **local**, I need to use

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8012/
```

As Config Server. Instead of

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://my.cloud.config.server:8012/
```

Comment: had you tried putting that last line in `application-local.properties`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this format: application-{env}.properties

For example, for local environment: application-local.properties file will do the work.

Answer (score 2):

Create profile application.properties files.

An example:

```
application.properties - defaults for all profiles.
application-local.properties - property values for the local profile
application-dev.properties - property values for the dev profile
application-kapow.properties - property values for the kapow profile
```

Note,
the profile name is your decision;
common values include: local, dev, qa, uat, and prod.
"kapow" is a valid profile name.
I've seen profiles defined by hostname.

Remember that you can have multiple profiles active at once.

Here is a link to a
[Baeldung article that discusses Spring profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)